# Android Studio ndk-build can't find files

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, opus

I 'm trying to compile OPUS in Android Studio.
When I call ndk-build from command line, everything works fine.
When I build it from Android Studio, it fails.

My app.gradle:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
    }
}
```

Android.mk has some includes:

```
include celt_sources.mk
```

The error:

```
Error while executing process G:\ASDK\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=F:\TP2\ram\android\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=F:\TP2\ram\android\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-19 NDK_OUT=F:/TP2/ram/android/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=F:\TP2\ram\android\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\release\lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
```

Why NDK_PROJECT_PATH null? How do I tell Android Studio to set the current directory before calling ndk-build?

Best,

Comment: `NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null` looks normal. What is the actual error?

Comment: It fails to compile, because it can't find the MK files. I temporarily resolved it by putting the full path in include statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27895191/192373) or similar solution to prepare opus for Android build. The statements like

```
include celt_sources.mk
```

are not a good practice, because they force you to run `ndk-build` in the same directory as the **Android.mk** file. It's not too hard to force Android Studio work this way, add the following block to your **build.gradle**:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                arguments '-C src/main/jni'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it is much cleaner to follow one of the many other versions of **Android.mk** for opus that can be found on the WWW, e.g. [this one](https://github.com/xen0n/android-ffmpeg-builder/blob/master/patches/libopus/Android.mk) which uses

```
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/celt_sources.mk
```

This way, the build doesn't depend on working directory for `ndk-build` command.